# Basic CSS trouble

Tags: css

I guess this is fairly simple for you but i cant wrap my head around it. I ripped out the important part. I got text inside #content so i cant change it and i dont want to use !important tag.
The css is presented in the order it is placed in my css file.

How come the "#content h2 a, #content h2 a:visited" overrides the .post-header h2 a?

```
<html>
    <head>
    .....
    </head>
    <div id="content">
    .....
        <div class="post-header">
            <a href="#">my text</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>


#content h2 a, #content h2 a:visited {
    font-family:"arial black","lucida console",sans-serif;
}

.post-header h2 a {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

/Joel

Comment: it overrides because the id-selector is considered more specific than the class-selector... quite simply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the browser checks the [**cascading order**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order). Since the declarations are all for the same media, importance, and origin, the rules are ordered by specificity.

Next, the browser calculates [**the selector's specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity), and (here's the important part for your question) `Id` selectors are higher priority than class selectors:

> A selector's specificity is calculated
>   as follows:
>
> - count 1 if the declaration is from is a 'style' attribute rather than a rule with a selector, 0
>     otherwise (= a) (In HTML, values of an element's "style" attribute are style sheet rules. These rules have no selectors, so a=1, b=0, c=0, and d=0.)
> - count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
> - count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
> - count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)
>
> The specificity is based only on the
>   form of the selector. In particular, a
>   selector of the form "[id=p33]" is
>   counted as an attribute selector (a=0,
>   b=0, c=1, d=0), even if the id
>   attribute is defined as an "ID" in the
>   source document's DTD.
>
> Concatenating the four numbers a-b-c-d (in a number system with a large base) gives the specificity.

Answer (score 5):

id is more specific than class. In your case you could add the id before the class.

```
#content .post-header h2 a {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
.post-header h2 a {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif!important;
}
```

To add additional priority to a CSS rule, and ensure that it overrides any others.

Comment: `!important` is a sledge hammer. It is generally best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Selectors based on ID's take precedent over selectors based on classes.

If you want your class-based style to override the ID selector, append a !important to the element style.

```
.post-header h2 a {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif !important;
}
```

!important doesn't work in IE6 though, if you care about those kind of things.